# Reindex magento2 on xampp on ubuntu

Tags: magento2

i installed magento 2 on xampp server bt i can't reindex the magento2.
i tried this:

```
sudo php var/www/html/magento
```

Otuput: Could not open input file: var/www/html/magento.

Please anybody explain me how to reindex?

Thanks.

Comment: >First you need to go magento installation folder using this command **cd /var/www/html/magento** 

>Now you are in your magento installation folder and now try with **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Comment: Now Try this command sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these cmd :

```
cd /var/www/html/magento
sudo bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Thanx @ashish. its working.